# In my case, How to highlight table row when mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

In my index.html page, I have an empty table defined as following:

```
<body>
  ...
  <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" class="mytable">
      <tr></tr>
  </table>
  <script src="my.js"></script>
</body>
```

As you saw above, there is an JavaScript file ***my.js*** is included.

***my.js***(which is used to update the table row):

```
var items = ARRAY_OF_OBJECTS_FROM_SERVER; //e.g. items=[{'John', '023567'},{'Bill', '055534'},...];

//Each object element in the "items" array contain "name" and "phone" attribute.

var mytable = $('.mytable tr:first');
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
   var obj = items[i];
   mytable.after("<tr>");
   mytable.after("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
   mytable.after(" <td>"+obj.name+"</td>");         
   mytable.after("<td>"+obj.phone+"</td>");
   mytable.after("</tr>");
}
```

I successfully get the dynamical table working, but when I try to add mouse hover effect on each row, I just failed. What I tried is by using CSS:

```
.mytable tr:hover
{ 
  background-color: #632a2a;
  color: #fff;
}
```

I would like the mouse hover with color highlight effect to be working on IE 7+, firefox and chrome, what is the correct way to implement the table row mouse hover effect in my case??

**----EDIT----**

Here is my index.html page:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>my test</title>
<link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
 <body>
      <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" class="mytable">
          <tr>
          </tr>
      </table>
  <script src="my.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**--SOLUTION----**

@manji 's solution solved my problem. That's change in JavaScript to use `append` instead of `after` inside for loop. Then, the CSS way of highlighting row is working.

Comment: `tr:hover` should work. Can you provide a jsfiddle example to show what's going wrong?

Comment: hover on css is technically suppose to be used for the `a ` tag hence why it might not work cross browser.

Comment: `tr:hover` definetly work. Your generated html is incorrect. Look at my answer for more explanation.

Comment: @manji, you just point at the exact place where the whole thing get stuck. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing the `<td>` outside of `<tr>` with this:

```
mytable.after("<tr>");
mytable.after("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
mytable.after(" <td>"+obj.name+"</td>");         
mytable.after("<td>"+obj.phone+"</td>");
mytable.after("</tr>");
```

For example, first one will add a `<tr>` and close it, then 3 closed `<td>s` before the `<tr>` and the last one is incorrect and will have no effect.

Try it this way and it will work:

```
mytable.after("<tr>"
+"<td>&nbsp;</td>"
+"<td>"+obj.name+"</td>"
+"<td>"+obj.phone+"</td>"
+"</tr>");
```

and it's better to use `.append()` (it will add the objects in their list order):

```
var mytable = $('.mytable');  // mytable selector is changed to select the table
                              // you can remove the empty <tr>
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
   var obj = items[i];
   mytable.append("<tr>"
   +"<td>&nbsp;</td>"
   +"<td>"+obj.name+"</td>"
   +"<td>"+obj.phone+"</td>"
   +"</tr>");
```

Comment: You are right! after I changed to use "append" in JS, the CSS way is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
.mytable tr:hover td
{ 
  background-color: #632a2a;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Given your list of browser support, CSS is the proper solution. It's important to note that the cells (`<td>`) cover the row (`<tr>`). So it's their background that you want to modify.

Comment: While a pure CSS solution is good, it is important to note that :hover on non anchor tags only works if you can get IE 7 into the html 4.01 strict doctype.

Comment: I tried your way, but nothing happened to my table row when mouseover, and I test it on firefox 4

Comment: @Jeremy, fair, but if you're not writing valid markup, you have far more problems than `:hover`. Especially in IE as it tiggers "quirks" mode.

Comment: @Leem, post your generated HTML and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Leem, works fine for me Mac + FF 3.6 - http://jsfiddle.net/qu7ZH/ Check your generated output is valid.

Comment: @Jason, it does not work in my case, because you have defined some value in the table tr td, but in my case, initially, I have empty content for tr , I fill content to table only by JavaScript code.

Comment: @Leem, as noted and you confirmed in your answer, your generated output was indeed invalid. The style I provided works given valid markup.

Answer (score 1):

You're best bet is to use jquery's hover: [Click Here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

IE 7 did not have hover support on elements other than anchor tags. (or maybe that was just 6) either way, since you are using jquery already you can get your hover effect done easily.

```
$("tr").hover(
     function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover_class');
     }, 
     function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover_class');
     }
);
```

Note: IE 7 will only allow :hover if you are running in HTML 4.01 STRICT for your doctype. Otherwise you need to use javascript to accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: It's just IE6 that doesn't support he `:hover` pseudo-class. As such jQuery is overkill in this case.

Comment: that would not work for future elements thou :), maybe should use live mouseenter,mouseleave combination

Comment: Jason you are incorrect. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/619c4492-ab7b-4a8e-b911-5fed8aa49457/ FROM MS themselves, it is altogether possible for IE7 to not respect :hover.

Comment: @val, not sure what you are talking about future elements for. About mousenter/mouseleave. Read the jquery docs, hover is shorthand for your thoughts.

Comment: Due to the doctype hoops you have to jump through to get hover to work in IE7, a JQuery solution seems sensible in this case.

Comment: @jeremy I talking about elements that are added to the table dynamically, thats why he should bind it with live, and use mouseenter as u can't use hover on live I think ?

Comment: @Val, good point. It depends on when he is doing the binding and if he is adding more elements after the initial create. Yes you are correct that hover and live don't get along so well.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot get the css solution to work use a `delegate` function to handle the dynamic rows.

```
$("table.mytable").delegate("tr", "hover", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: why use a delegate when you can use `.hover()` directly?

Comment: @PeeHaa - because he is generating the table client side instead of rendering the html from the server. Depending on which happens first, the ready event, or the table output, a direct call to hover could miss the dynamically added rows.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$('.mytable tr').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
.mytable tr.active td
{ 
  background-color: #632a2a;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Check out the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JpJFC/

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery delegate method which is the best way to do it from performance point of view.

```
$(".mytable").delegate("tr", "mouseover", function(e) {

                $(this).addClass('mouseoverClass');

            });

$(".mytable").delegate("tr", "mouseout", function(e) {

                $(this).removeClass('mouseoverClass');

            });
```